# How to get last update time of each partition in a table in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I am storing a table in `Azure cosmos DB` which has a lot of partitions. I want to query content only for those partitions which had any update in last X minutes. Is there a way to efficiently query the list of partition keys which were updated in last X minutes? - Since cross partition queries can turn out to be really expensive.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this efficiently is to store the last update time in it's own container with a single logical partition and a composite index with desc sort on your `lastUpdated` property.

```
{
   "id": "xxxx",
   "pk": "0000",
   "pkValue": "pk value from other container",
   "lastUpdated": "2020-06-21T23:14:25.7251173Z"
}
```

Make sure you use the ISO 8601 UTC standard for datetime strings, see [DateTime in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes). Also see docs on [Composite Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#composite-indexes)

The question to answer though is whether this is more cost efficient than doing cross partition queries. If as you say there is a lot of data across many physical partitions then it likely could be. This you will have to determine though.

Hope this is helpful.